# Postback without clicking button in VB.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, postback

My code currently requires me to click the button to post the information back to the server, is there any way of doing this automically with code, basically to simulate clicking the button or better, post it back without any buttons?

ASPX code:

```
           <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

                <%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>

                <!DOCTYPE html>


                  <form id="form1" runat="server">
                      <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
                          <Scripts>
                              <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
                              </asp:ScriptReference>
                              <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
                              </asp:ScriptReference>
                              <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
                              </asp:ScriptReference>
                          </Scripts>
                      </telerik:RadScriptManager>


                  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="svgHolder" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Export the RadHtmlChart" OnClientClick="getSvgContent(this);"
            runat="server" />
    <table class="clearTable2" style="page-break-after: avoid;">
        <tr>
            <td class="clearTable1"></td>
            <td class="clearTable2">
                <asp:Label ID="lblSectionTitle" runat="server" CssClass="label2"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="clearTable1"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="clearTable2">
        <tr>
            <td class="clearTable1"></td>
            <td class="clearTable1" style="width: 100%; visibility: visible">

                <telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" ID="RadHtmlChart1">
                    <Legend>
                        <Appearance Position="Bottom">
                            <TextStyle FontSize="14" Color="Blue" FontFamily="Courier New, sans-serif" />
                        </Appearance>
                    </Legend>
                    <PlotArea>
                        <XAxis>
                            <Items>
                                <telerik:AxisItem LabelText="KM41872"/>
                                <telerik:AxisItem LabelText="KM41873"/>
                                <telerik:AxisItem LabelText="KM41871"/>
                            </Items>
                            <MajorGridLines Visible="false" />
                            <MinorGridLines Visible="false" />
                        </XAxis>
                        <YAxis>
                            <MinorGridLines Visible="false" />
                        </YAxis>
                        <Series>
                            <telerik:LineSeries Name="Mean">
                                <SeriesItems>
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.59" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.63" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.6" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.65" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.64" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.63" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.65" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.67" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.63" />
                                </SeriesItems>
                            </telerik:LineSeries>
                            <telerik:LineSeries Name="Min">
                                <SeriesItems>
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.55" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.56" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.55" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.61" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.56" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.57" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.59" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.61" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.55" />
                                </SeriesItems>
                            </telerik:LineSeries>
                            <telerik:LineSeries Name="Max">
                                <SeriesItems>
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.66" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.74" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.66" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.71" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.72" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.73" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.71" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.74" />
                                    <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.71" />
                                </SeriesItems>
                            </telerik:LineSeries>
                        </Series>
                    </PlotArea>
                </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
            </td>
            <td class="clearTable1"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getSvgContent(sender) {
            //obtain an SVG version of the chart regardless of the browser
            var chartRendering = $find("<%=RadHtmlChart1.ClientID %>").getSVGString();
            //store the SVG string in a hidden field and escape it so that the value can be posted to the server
            document.getElementById('<%=svgHolder.ClientID%>').value = escape(chartRendering);
            //initiate the postback from the button so that its server-side handler is executed
            __doPostBack(sender.name, "");
            $('#Button1').click();
        }
    </script>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

CodeBehind:
    Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Button1.Text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(svgHolder.Value)

End Sub


'Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
'    Dim svgText As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(svgHolder.Value)
'End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hook JavaScript up to the client side event you want the page to postback on. Then use JavaScript to "click" the button in the event handler.

Comment: the $('#Button1').click(); in my code simulates the "click" but it seems to have no effect

Comment: Your code does some client side stuff, then would postback to the server. Most likely that's not what you want, because you'll lose your client side changes. You also state in your question that you'd like to eliminate the button, but you don't say when you'd like it to run (run event it should be wired up to).

Comment: I basically just want to receive the svg portion of my htmlchart, but right now it only works if I click the button on the aspx page that is loaded up in the browser. I want it to automatically be sent back if possible.

Comment: I understand that, but you need to understand that things don't just happen on their own, you have to hook them up to a certain event. That's called event driven. If you want it to automatically do something on the server side you should use the Page_Load method on the server side, and then there would be no need for JavaScript. Otherwise if you want to do it on client side, figure out what event you need to have it run in response to, then hook it up to that event, either by simulating a buttong click or directly calling `__doPosBack`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function DoPostBack(obj) {
            __doPostBack(obj.id, 'OtherParams');
}

Just call __doPostBack
```

Comment: is this posting back a specific object?

Comment: Yes... Just create a button it make it hidden on the page by wrapping it with a div <div style='display:none'>MYBUTTON</div>. Then use that button for the postback. That way you can even handle it conveniently with a specified event on the server.

Comment: This is off the top of my head and untested...                  <div style='display:none'><asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnRibbonChanged" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnRibbonChanged_Click"> </asp:LinkButton></div>


... then.... $('#lbtnRibbonChanged').click()
This is simpler than calling __doPostBack, but __doPostBack can be useful if you don't want to use a button and need to postback a specific control. If you just want to trigger a postback and handle it on the server, this is the best way. Make sure ClientIDMode is Static so it can find the button.

Answer (score 0):

What you want I think is the __dopostback javascript function (google it).  It essentially fakes a post back event from a .Net control so it will work just like as if your button was clicked.  You could also set the diplay:hidden property of the button if you don't want it show but still hook into it for a postback.

Comment: right now, what I have does not work, I have to physically click the button for it to post back for some reason, but what I'm trying to accomplish is to load the page with the postback already accomplished or to simulate it somehow

Comment: For bonus points you could make this seamless by making your server side page method ajax'ed by decorating it with [webmethod] http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: Remove the sender.name with the button's name.